# LINQ to SQL and configuring it not to use TOP

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

We are using SQL Server 2005 with linq to sql in the code.

We noticed a slowdown (3 minutes versus a 4 second return for 100 records) when a TOP 300 is used in the following scenario.

```
SELECT TOP (300) {fields HERE} FROM {database} WHERE {where clauses with a nested select} ORDER BY {order by values}
```

This is getting created by linq because .Skip(0).Take(300).ToList<>() is being called.

When the .Skip(300).Take(300).ToList<>() is called linq converts that to a ROW_NUMBER instead of a TOP and the problem is eliminated.

Is there a workaround for linq to not use TOP?

I've read a few blogs about the problem with TOP is that when you TOP for 101 records or more it used the tempdb to do the sorting instead of in memory.

Comment: do you have to get rid of TOP or just want that code faster?

Comment: Just want the code faster but I have to keep the linq to sql

Answer (score 0):

We are using TOP a lot and never had a performance problem with it before.

Maybe you are just running into the "ARITHABORT is off by default" issue?

Call before your select:

```
new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a movie database (50'000 movies registered in it). The way how I bring this list to the webpage is pager. Logic is completely generated in SQL

```
WITH ct1 as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some condition) num,
    {my fields}
)
SELECT {my fields} FROM ct1 
WHERE num BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @ItemsPerPage + 1 
AND @PageNum * @ItemsPerPage
```

Takes less than a second for more than 50'000 records.

Comment: I agree. I have noticed that row_number() is way faster!! The problem that I've noticed is that you want to use linq .take(300) records (the beginning in the group), it automatically does a TOP and that is what I want to turn off.